# What is the time complexity of the following loop?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

```
function (n)
    i = 1
    s = 1
    while (s <= n)
        i = i+1
        s = s*i
        print "*"
end
```

Comment: This place isn't a machine that answers questions. You should have formatted your message and gave what you've tried to solve this.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new to this place. I'll definitely do that next time.

Comment: @dylan61 The problem here isn't the formatting. It's that the question is just a problem dump ("Here's an exercise -- please solve it for me!") and that it's already covered by our reference question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all operations are done in constant time, this loop runs in $\Theta(n!^{-1})$ where $!^{-1}$ is the inverse factorial. Intuitively, the program will enter the loop $i$ times, $i$ being the smallest integer so that $i!\geq n$.

Comment: Thanks. I've never come across this function while computing complexity. Is this function O(log(n))

Comment: Factorial grows faster than exponential. Hence, the natural logarithm (the inverse of the exponential) grows faster than the inverse of the factorial. It follows (if you change the logarithm's base) that the inverse factorial is indeed $O(\log n)$.